# Photon Connection from IPv4 clients to IPv6-only photon server

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, server, photon

Just as the title says,

Not all ISP in our country support IPv6 yet, some does, some doesnt,
I dont want to create a situation where players can only play our game only if
he/she has a certain "IPv6 enabled" ISP. That won't be great. The ISP I used support IPv6.

My server(pc) is set behind a series of NAT, (I dun know the architecture but port-forwarding from the router is not enough, it has its own "local" ipv4-address from its "parent"(I don't know the ip-address of the parent)). Also I have contacted them, to give me a public IPv4 but unfortunately, it didn't go well as planned.

At the start, I tried to use IPv4 address given by "whatismyip.com", but well it gives the IP address of my ISP, not my router or my PC.

And then, there is this, I can access the server via IPv6 connections. But can't via IPv4. so how can I establish the connection between the two? How can I solve it?
(Please feel free to ask about any more information that is needed, I just recently started to learn networking so they are lots of things i might be wrong about, sorry in advance)

Thanks in advance! UwU

Comment: IPv4 and IPv6 are two completely separate, incompatible protocols, and one cannot directly connect to the other. Also, you have a residential network using CGN, and your contract with the ISP forbids running services to the Internet, so your ISP does not really care that this does not work. You need a business Internet connection.

Comment: yea, sorry for late reply, i have a set up a domain name and get a public ipv4 address to get this job done, thank you tho